# ReactJS - Simple Server Side API Request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, cors

I'm making a very simple API axios.get request in ReactJS, client side.  However, it gets blocked by CORS in my browser.  So no data gets returned.

I understand I need to make this request server side, but I'm not sure how I should restructure my code below, (to be written server side).

Any tips on how to rewrite this code, would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

```
  // MAKE JOB API REQUEST
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('COMPONENT DID MOUNT');
    axios.get('https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?search=')

      .then(res => {
        console.log('jobs', res.data.slice(0, 9));

        this.setState(
          { jobs: res.data.slice(0, 9) }
        );
      });
  }
```

Comment: Create a route in your server that in turn sends a request to `https://jobs.github.com/positions.json`, and that sends the github response back as response.

Comment: CORS must be set by the owner of server to work, u can cheat a little by load this githuburl over a php page and load this php page with axios(i dont know if this the best solution)

Comment: @Tholle - thank you - how would I do this?

Comment: @Reena Verma i think he mean a route on apache/nginx which route a local path to the external path aka proxypass

Comment: @ReenaVerma It depends on what kind of server you have.

Comment: @Tholle - ok, im just using my local node/express server.  Nothing fancy, i'm just running a basic react app.  Here it is on guthub https://github.com/ReenaVerma/REACT-JOB-BOARD

Comment: @ReenaVerma You [can create an express route](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) that does all the work and just sends the final github position objects as response.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, you need to create a route for that and use proxy to handle the requests. Here is the steps:

**webpack.config.js**

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: ['src'],
    watchContentBase: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    port: 8000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:4000/',
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },
```

**index.js**

```
const axios = require( "axios" );

...skipped codes

app.get( "/api/jobs", ( req, res ) => {
  axios.get( `https://jobs.github.com/positions.json?search=${ req.query.job }` )
    .then( result => res.send( result.data ) );
} );
```

You need to require `axios` in this file also as you see.

**app.js**

```
handleSubmit = ( e ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { searchData } = this.state;

    axios.get( `/api/jobs?job=${ searchData }` )
      .then( res => this.setState( { jobs: res.data } ) );
}
```

There was no `componentDidMount` in your code so I used `handleSubmit`. With this setup whenever you made a request to `/api/something` it redirects to your Express server. So, on the front-end you will use `/api` and you will add the needed routes to your Express setup.

Comment: thank you! I will implement this solution this evening and let you know how I get on... Thank you!